If a 4D being rotates a sphere in their 4D space, how would we perceive this rotation in our 3D world? Would the sphere appear to elongate?
Imagine a hypothetical scenario where a 2D being resides in a 2D world, observing a circle placed in front of them. Now, suppose we have control over their 2D environment and rotate a 2D circle axially in a third dimension (3D). As the circle undergoes this rotation, the 2D being would perceive it as transforming into an ellipse and eventually into a straight line after a 90° axial rotation in the third dimension.
Now, let's consider a similar scenario in a higher-dimensional context: a 4D being rotates a perfect sphere in their 4D space. As observers in our 3D world, how would we perceive this rotation? Would the sphere appear to elongate into an egg-like shape, and what would it look like after a 90° axial rotation in the fourth dimension? Would it resemble a cone or exhibit other complex transformations?
I'm curious about how higher-dimensional rotations could manifest visually in our lower-dimensional perception. Any insights or explanations would be greatly appreciated!

Your first example involves a 2D disc being rotated in 3D space and then projected back down to a 2D plane. Assuming the axis of rotation is parallel to the 2D plane then the projection on the 2D plane will have a constant width along a line parallel to this axis and a varying width along a line perpendicular to the axis. So, yes, the projection will transform from a circle through a sequence of ellipses to a 1D line, and then back to a circle again.
If we take this up one dimension then we will have a 3D sphere being rotated in 4D space and projected back down to a 3D space. 4D rotations are more complex than 3D rotations because you have more choices to make about invariant axes. However, if we assume that there are two invariant axes in 4D space that are parallel to the 3D space then the dimensions of the projected 3D sphere will be constant along two dimensions and will change along a third dimension. So the projection in the 3D space will transform from a 3D sphere through a sequence of spheroids until it becomes a 2D disc, and will then transform back to a 3D sphere again.

But there's a problem at 90°. A 2d abject is 2d because it doesn't have length in direction perpendicular to its world. So, now at 90 there shouldn't be a line or there there should be a 1d line that don't have any width. Also I think about another idea to comprehend 4d actions in 3d world. I think that any transformation done by a 4d being in 3d will look like the same transformation done by 3d being to 2d world rotated axially. Like if some 4d being passes a 4d sphere from 3d world it will look like the sphere is getting smaller and larger in size.
